# Orientation change causes font size changes

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` embedded in a `UIViewController` and I'm having some really weird behavior when the device is rotated. My text has a font size set (in css) at `11px`, but when I rotate to landscape, the font is resized to `19px` (according to Safari) and I can't figure out where that re-calculation is coming from. Even stranger, another (single line) `div` right above it has a font size of `10px` and doesn't get resized.

I have something like this:

```
<div class="date">Sep 16</div>
<div class="body"><span class="bold">blah:</span> blah, blah</div>
```

With css something like:

```
div.date {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}

div.body {
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `body` get resized while `date` doesn't. I'm not sure if the problem is HTML / CSS or with the settings on the `UIWebView`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you found solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Safari [automatically resizes an scales the viewport on orientation changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW29) and will take some liberties with elements in the root `<body>` tag.

The goal Safari has in mind is to fill the screen with content, so if your content doesn't quite fill the space, Safari will scale up some elements to fill it.

You can set some attributes such as `minimum-scale` and `maximum-scale` as well as setting the `viewport`'s `width` size if you want a specific behavior.

Comment: I've tried setting `minimum-scale`, `maximum-scale`, `initial-scale` and `user-scalable=no` to no effect. Annoyingly, if you are in landscape before you load the view, it looks fine, but if you then switch to portrait (looks fine - no rescaling) then back to landscape, it's all screwed up again!

Comment: Mobile Safari is loaded with fun quirks like this... I would just put everything in a `div` block if that solves it for you.

Comment: These are actually already wrapped in another div with `width` set to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

You may reload `WebView` again while orientation. This works for me.

Use below methods in your `ViewController`:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints {
  [super updateViewConstraints];
  [yourWebView loadHTMLString:yourHTMLString baseURL:nil];
}
```